# is it possible to edit/modify the firefox addons after installing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to modify/edit, already installed firefox addons? Where are the addons stored in the computer... I mean which folder etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The addons/extensions are stored under Linux in: `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default/extensions`. The `profile` part of the path will be different.

Comment: In Windows, that location is %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile}.default\extensions

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer.  In addition to the finding the folder, FF addons are now signed, so modifying them is not so straight forward, and I don't have an answer for this yet.

Comment: Circumvent requirements for signed add-ons as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794754/156973 - @gone

Answer (score 31):

It is possible to edit the files. Its simple to find the folder path.

- Open the Help menu from the browser top menu
- select Troubleshooting Information option. The Troubleshooting
  Information tab will open.
- Under the Application Basics section, click on Show Folder. A window
  with your profile files will open.
- Open the 'extensions' folder in there.

you should find all the extension files in here. Your extension could be a .xpi file which is nothing but a zip file. copy it to a different folder and rename it to .zip. Unzip it and browse the content in it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that when you want to enable this edited version of the add-on, firefox will complain that it is not signed and will have disabled it by default. You can override this behaviour by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required`:`false` in `about:config`, but that will open an security hole in your configuration.

Answer (score 9):

For me (Windows) they are now stored in `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\YOUR_PROFILE.default\extensions\`

And there you copy your add-on with the id found in install.rdf inside of your .xpi zip file as the name. Such as: `jid0-UNAwlo81XedDjh0Suj64AGkhDaj@jetpack.xpi`

But on Firefox restart **you will be prompted to confirm installation**. Not good for a development script.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to modify them if you find the path where it is installed. You would have to restart Firefox everytime you make a change to these source files though. The uninstall function cleanly deletes the addon from your extensions directory and you can view and delete preferences you have set for the extension in the 'about:config' page.

On Windows, that path is usually c:/Document and Settings/(your username)/Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/(usually default)/extensions

If you delete a folder(extension) from the extensions directory, it has the same effect as uninstalling it.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to find your profile folder ([instructions](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles)) and then find the folder called "extensions".  In there, there will be a folder for each add-on you have installed.

Note that each time an add-on is updated, your changes will be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox extensions reside on :

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile}.default\extensions
```

Each extension will have its ID as a filename along with a `.xpi` extension.

To find out which ID belongs to an installed extension name visit [`about:support`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/About_URI_scheme) and consult the table titled `Extensions`.

Beware that modifying an extension will result in Firefox disabling it on the next launch as it will [no longer match its authenticity signature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox). A special edition of Firefox, like Nightly, Developers or ESR is required to [alter that behavior](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox#w_what-can-i-do-if-firefox-disables-an-installed-add-on).