# How to edit a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to change a Firefox extension. What I've done is found it in the Firefox profile folder, renamed the .jar to .zip, unzipped it, made the changes in a .js file (I didn't make a mistake in JS code), zipped it back and renamed to .jar. So now the button to start that extension has disappeared from the menu in Firefox :) What is the proper way to bring minor changes to a Firefox plugin?

**Update:**
I've tried to make the changes minimum to test if it'll work: I've replaced

```
stepsVariations.push(new WTRStep("clickButton", {label: _oTarget.alt}))
```

with

```
stepsVariations.push(new WTRStep("clickButton", {label: _oTarget.alt+"test"}))
```

*still the same*

**Update:**
I've tried the .xpi thing, still the same - not even a button in the menu.

Comment: Thats the way. I think you've made some mistake in editing.

Comment: I've done this (not jar, modifying plain JS - that extension wasn't jar'ed) and it has worked for me. Did you by any chance rename the file wrongly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing existing Firefox Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438855/editing-existing-firefox-add-on)

Comment: Actually, it's better off being marked as a duplicate of [is it possible to edit/modify the firefox addons after installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054570/is-it-possible-to-edit-modify-the-firefox-addons-after-installing) since that one has more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest getting the .xpi from addons.mozilla or the original site. Rename it to zip and do your changes, then rename it back to .xpi and open it with Firefox, it will be installed over the old one. See if it makes a difference.

Comment: I would never imagine to rename the extension to *.zip. Kudos for the tip.