# Why are some Firefox extensions fully extracted in install directory and others not?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi

Looking in the Firefox extensions directory (See [location of Firefox installed extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054570/is-it-possible-to-edit-modify-the-firefox-addons-after-installing)), I see that some have .xpi files alone, but others have directories:

```
c:/Users/CENSORED/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/CENSORED.default/extensions:
total used in directory 5241 available 56453112
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-25 07:49 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-25 09:32 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  164722 03-04 09:37 compatibility@addons.mozilla.org.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None    8359 03-10 12:38 copy-pure-text@kashiif-gmail.com.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   75035 03-04 09:37 extensionlistdumper@sogame.cat.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None 1331409 03-04 09:37 firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-22 17:57 inspector@mozilla.org
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   37714 03-04 09:37 lockthetext@lockthetext.sourceforge.net.xpi
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-04 09:31 sharing@addons.mozilla.org
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   97169 03-04 09:37 {3d7eb24f-2740-49df-8937-200b1cc08f8a}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  258567 03-04 09:37 {46551EC9-40F0-4e47-8E18-8E5CF550CFB8}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  220407 03-04 09:37 {73c39a20-8768-4a82-8b43-fc9535715c5c}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  516216 03-04 09:37 {7f57cf46-4467-4c2d-adfa-0cba7c507e54}.xpi
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-04 09:37 {81BF1D23-5F17-408D-AC6B-BD6DF7CAF670}
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   89442 03-04 09:37 {B17C1C5A-04B1-11DB-9804-B622A1EF5492}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  709293 03-04 09:37 {DDC359D1-844A-42a7-9AA1-88A850A938A8}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   27409 03-04 09:36 {E6175356-15A3-11DF-AFEE-C56455D89593}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None     876 03-25 07:49 {F78DC607-BB30-4e13-9E47-2C2E162E9094}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   52880 03-04 09:37 {a0faa0a4-f1a7-4098-9a74-21efc3a92372}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  413408 03-04 09:37 {c45c406e-ab73-11d8-be73-000a95be3b12}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  634964 03-04 09:37 {d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None  686225 03-24 08:07 {dc572301-7619-498c-a57d-39143191b318}.xpi
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-04 09:37 {e4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781}
-rw-rw-rw-  1 CENSORED None   41715 03-24 08:55 {e6c4c3ef-3d4d-42d6-8283-8da73c53a283}.xpi
drwxrwxrwx  1 CENSORED None       0 03-10 12:38 {fc2b8f80-d9a5-4f51-8076-7c7ce3c67ee3}
```

For instance, `{e6c4c3ef-3d4d-42d6-8283-8da73c53a283}.xpi` is a file, while `{e4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781}` is a directory of files.

Why are some extracted fully and others not?

Comment: This seems to belong on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Firefox 4 all extensions were extracted when installed. This behavior changed, the new default is to keep the extension as packed `.xpi` file for performance reasons.

Extensions can still opt into the old behavior by specifying [`<em:unpack>` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#unpack). I've seen some extensions use this flag for no good reason whatsoever, others do it because they rely on a particular way to access their files (especially all add-ons created with the Add-on SDK before Add-on SDK 1.5).

In some cases it is really unavoidable that the extension is installed unpacked, most commonly for extensions containing binary XPCOM components or plugins - the operating system needs an actual file to load the dynamic library, it cannot be loaded from inside an archive.